# Gradle IDEA configuration

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I read [here](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.IdeaModule.html) that I can tweak certain settings using these parameters:

```
idea {
    module {
        downloadJavadoc = false    
        downloadSources = true
    }
}
```

However I get an error when I am trying to build:

```
Could not find method idea() for arguments
```

Comment: Did you apply idea plugin? `apply plugin: 'idea'`

Comment: No, I did not. I will accept this as a solution, if you post it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Please apply the IDEA plugin first:

`apply plugin: 'idea'`